# Prevent dropping of IPv6 Router Solicitation (Type 133) packets

Tags: iptables, firewall, firehol

I am seeing journal entries such as the following, which appear at regular 4-second intervals:

```
Jan 22 19:31:00 tara kernel: OUT-global:IN= OUT=enp3s0f2 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:56e4:c37c:30cc:668f DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=158870 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0
Jan 22 19:31:04 tara kernel: OUT-global:IN= OUT=enp3s0f2 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:56e4:c37c:30cc:668f DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=158870 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0
Jan 22 19:31:08 tara kernel: OUT-global:IN= OUT=enp3s0f2 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:56e4:c37c:30cc:668f DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=158870 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0
Jan 22 19:31:12 tara kernel: OUT-global:IN= OUT=enp3s0f2 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:56e4:c37c:30cc:668f DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=158870 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0
```

[RFC4890 - Recommendations for Filtering ICMPv6 Messages in Firewalls](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4890.txt) lists `Router Solicitation (Type 133)`
in `Section 4.4.1 - Traffic That Must Not Be Dropped`.

But it seems that my configuration is indeed dropping them.

My iptables are generated by [`firehol`](https://firehol.org/), configured thus:

```
version 6

# ssh on port 5090 (ssh is a built-in service name)
server_ssh_hidden_ports="tcp/5090"
client_ssh_hidden_ports="default"

# mosh
server_mosh_ports="udp/60001:60020" # Mosh uses 60001 to 60999 counting up
client_mosh_ports="default"

# NoMachine (nxserver is a built-in, but seemingly on incorrect ports)
server_nomachine_ports="tcp/4000"
client_nomachine_ports="default"

# Deluge
server_deluge_ports="tcp/8112"
client_deluge_ports="default"

# Zerotier-one
interface zt0 zerotier
        policy reject # be nicer than default "drop" on internal network
        protection strong

        server "ssh_hidden mosh" accept with limit 8/min 10 # rate/period [burst]
        server "nomachine deluge" accept with limit 8/min 10 # rate/period [burst]
        #server "ssh_hidden nomachine" accept with recent recent-zerotier 30 6 # name, seconds, attempts per period

        client all accept

# All interfaces - look at fallthrough if putting this non-last as it didn't work without it
interface any global
        protection strong
        server ssh_hidden accept with limit 8/min 10
        client all accept
```

How do I remove these noisy log messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [FireHOL IPv6 Setup](https://firehol.org/tutorial/firehol-ipv6/), add the following to the top of your `firehol.conf`:

> ```
> ipv6 interface any v6interop proto icmpv6
>   client ipv6neigh accept
>   server ipv6neigh accept
>   client ipv6mld accept
>   client ipv6router accept
>   policy return
> ```